# convert python float to 32 bit object

Tags: python, c++, floating-point, double

I'm trying to use python to investigate the effect of C++ truncating doubles to floats.

In C++ I have relativistic energies and momenta which are cast to floats, and I'm trying to work out whether at these energies saving them as doubles would actually result in any improved precision in the difference between energy and momentum.

I chose python because it seemed like a quick and easy way to look at this with some test energies, but now I realise that the difference between C++ 32 bit floats and 64 bit doubles isn't reflect in python.

I haven't yet found a simple way of taking a number and reducing the number of bits used to store it in python. Please can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Choosing Python seems strange. If you want to check the bahvior of `float` vs `double` in c++ - why not use c++ ?

Comment: Before starting I expected the same behaviour from `float` and `double` in both languages, and I chose python because I hope it would be quick and easy, and also because it seemed like a good opportunity to practice writing in python

Comment: `PyFloat_Pack4` or `PyFloat_AsDouble` may help? https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/float.html but it might always be stored as `double` on the python side, instead of `float`. Maybe `numpy.float32` would work.

Comment: @Brandon How do you use that? When I type `PyFloat_Pack4(variable)` it gives me `NameError: name 'PyFloat_Pack4' is not defined`

Comment: @BethLong `PyFloat_Pack4` is new with Python version 3.11

Comment: @BethLong those are part of the C API, hence they're available to extension modules written in C.  The equivalent in Python would be the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using Numpy as well.  It exposes various [data types](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html) including C style `float`s and `double`s.

Other useful tools are the C++17 style [hex encoding](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#float.hex) and the [`decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) for getting accurate decimal expansions.

For example:

```py
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal

for ftype in (np.float32, np.float64):
    v = np.exp(ftype(1))
    pyf = float(v)
    print(f"{v.dtype} {v:20} {pyf.hex()} {Decimal(pyf)}")
```

giving

```
float32   2.7182819843292236 0x1.5bf0aa0000000p+1 2.7182819843292236328125
float64    2.718281828459045 0x1.5bf0a8b145769p+1 2.718281828459045090795598298427648842334747314453125
```

Unfortunately the hex-encoding is a bit verbose for `float32`s (i.e. the zeros are redundant), and the decimal module doesn't know about Numpy floats, so you need to convert it to a Python-native float first.  But given that binary32's can be directly converted to binary64's this doesn't seem too bad.

Just thought, that it sounds like you might want these written out to a file.  If so, Numpy scalars (and ndarrays) support the [buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html), which means you can just write them out or use `bytes(v)` to get the underlying bytes.

Comment: `np.float32` was exactly what I was looking for, thank you